# Scripting camera in Unity 5 to be controlled by mouse movement so that the character is always moving forward?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have my character animated and she is able to walk in 4 directions, but I'm having a hard time making some sort of target on her or something that will make my camera rotate every time my character rotates.

I'm using C# for scripting.

Comment: I came really close with adding Mouse Look script on my char, but when I press W my char still follows the direction that is previously set - she is positioned forward but she's still moving in the other direction.

Comment: Why don't you include the code you used to achieve this behaviour? Edit it into your question. If you came really close to the solution, we don't want to throw away all your work - it'd be best if we could examine and work off of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Character should be parent of camera and you should rotate character instead of camera. I used this to rotate camera with mouse button so you can implement it to rotate character with keyboard.

```
public float sensX = 100.0f;
float rotationX = 0.0f;

void Update () {

    if (Input.GetMouseButton (0)) {
        rotationX += Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X") * sensX * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3 (0, rotationX, 0);
    }
}
```